# Automated performance testing

Tags: unity, performance, testing

I'm wondering if there's anyway of automatically testing the performance of my game on multiple configurations because I know a game runs well on my computer but how do I know how well my game performs over a variety of hardware? Do I just simply have to rely on player feedback?